# 2 volts Agnd, 1000 Gigaohms resistor questions

Tags: operational-amplifier

I found the slide presentation of the circuits in much more detail here.

https://slideplayer.com/slide/4563865/

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So the 2 volts is part of the circuit design. So it's not Aground? It's identical to my actual board except the 10MOhm input is also connected to the 2 volts in my original illustration. Won't the op-amps work without the 2 volts above?

I don't want to make a new thread but if you can show computations how the circuit work, please share it here so we can understand the need for 2 volts Aground (or whatever).

[image]

All the voltages in red were measured with respect to real ground. The user ground is connected directly to real ground as tested with my multimeter continuity probe. The Agrnd (analog ground) are all 2 volts. I think the reason most show 2V is because I'm using a multimeter and not oscilloscope which can show waveforms.

(addition: Using a voltmeter, I measured the Vout and Vin of the negative feedback op-amps at 2 volts (Agrd). The Vrh to the 68HC11 measured at 4 volts. The electrode socket input at 1 volt. The input to the HC11 ADC converter at 2.454 volts. So the stage 2 op-amp produce gain of 0.454 volts at idle.)

In 1998, the company shared this Brainmaster 2E EEG as open source. A year later I bought a unit for support (it used the Op490 instead of 2 Op90,) but never used it for 20 years until now.

I want to take the opportunity to learn about the circuit. Right now, the improved model changed the input impedance from 10M ohm to 1000 Gigaohm. Also it changed the CMMR from 100db to 120db.

1. Why is the negative feedback OP90 op-amp at rightmost which I measured to have Vout 2 volts powering the Agrd (analog ground) of the circuit? Can it improve it compared to if Agnd is merely 0 volts? What external circuit can I replace the 2 volts driver at right so it can output even much cleaner Agrnd?
2. Do I just replace the resistor to change the input impedance from 10Megaohm to 1000 Gigaohm?  Note in the actual circuit, the 10M inputs ground are connected to the aground (I traced it many times and sure of it.)
3. To improve the CMMR from 100db to 120db, hat else should be changed? Is it only the 1000Gigaohm resistor that must replace the 10Mohm resistor?

(edit, it was 1000 GOhms as this description in 2006 mentioned. My model has only 10MOhms and not even 10GOhms)

[image]

Comment: 2000 GOhm (or 1000, I can't tell what you want exactly) is insanely difficult because epoxy packaging used for ICs will leak more than that. So you cannot use an IC's epoxy package. Similar is true for the board layout, which will likely need special treatments along with carefully designed cut-outs and more. Yeah. *Just replace the resistor.* Not very likely. (In my most extreme case in my life I literally had to beg for dice in a waffle pack and then go borrow a wire-bonder to get down to the level you are talking about. It is NOT easy.)

Comment: i dont get it. what does epoxy packaging leaking (whatvet it means) got to do with a 2000 GOhm resistor?

Comment: @Jtl The stuff that the resistor is encased in (the packaging) literally has a resistance lower than 2000GOhm. Instead of the electricity flowing through the resistor, you'll get it flowing through its coating.

Comment: Imagine a river. A river is confined to the path it flows because that path is the lowest path in the land. If the land is level, the river spill out all over the place and flows everywhere. In the same way, current flows in a circuit because the resistance in the traces and wires are much lower than everything else on the board so the vast majority of current flows through the traces and components and a negligible amount flows through the PCB dielectric and other insulators.

Comment: But if both your resistor and and insulators are near the same resistance, how is the current supposed to know that you want most of the current to flow only through the resistor and not through the insulators? It doesn't. You just lost the well defined current path in your circuit. This is the reason we have electric circuits but not heat circuits. The conductivity difference between conductors and insulators for electricity is vast so you can get well defined paths, but for thermal is too low is too low and everything spills and smears out with no path. You can see this in a thermal camera.

Comment: 1000 gigaOhms is a very high resistance. Stupidly high.  Such a resistor would be near impossible to purchase. Resistors above 10M start to become more specialised. The opamp might have an input impedance of 1000GOhm, but to physically achieve that would require great care and special pcb material if any. Its hard to decipher the schematic, but i would guess the opamp on the rhs is creating a virtual earth which is needed since you only have a unipolar power supply. The resistors set the voltage and the opamp is just a buffer.

Comment: Probably need rogers 4350B for a PCB to maintain that low leakage, for a 4x5inch pcb its about 500$

Comment: I think that update must refer specifically to the op-amp used.  The only relevant upgrade is the CMRR.

Comment: The way you typically get very high input impedances is by bootstrapping the input resistors, (And often by guard rings and actively driven 'leg electrodes' in medical applications). This I think is what your blue line is trying to do, but I think 'user ground' and agnd are different things... Layout is going to MATTER to making this work, and I doubt you are getting 1TOhm...

Comment: 10 megohm is liable to be adequate. Failing that, the largest resistors that you can buy - but its not obvious that they are in fact requiring 100 gigohm resistors.

Comment: User ground is connected to real ground. My input resistor is 20MOhm. not 1000MOhm. which is their claimed resistor in latest model. Anyway. something puzzled me. Why do I measure 1.09V at the input? I repeated the measurments dozens of times. Is 1.09V what happens when you put a 20MOhm resistor with 2V Aground and measured with respect to real ground? or is 1.09V the input pins -IN and +IN with respect to real ground? (see edited schematic with voltages shown at major pins)

Comment: In my unit, the negative feedback op-amp has socket so tomorrow I plan to remove the OP90 chip and connect  all the Aground direct to Ground and see the software output. But let me know if there could be catastrophic failure of the circuit. I spent 2 months studying assembly language of the Hc11 so I can recreate the firmware which got trashed when I ran their latest software after keeping the unit for 20 years in the attic. Now I'm very familiar with machine language like using the Real Time Interrupt. However I still don't know how they can time the 2 channels and passing via one serial port

Comment: I removed the negative feedback op90 and connected Aground direct to ground. I only got a flat 4.4volts at the output to the input of the ADC of the HC11. Its as if with zero ground, there is bigger differential at op amps inputs. These are just simple components. Can someone help put these in Splice and share why the output of all ground connection is a flat 4.4V with no waveforms of any kind?

Answer (score 3):

Input impedance specs for FET input amplifiers can be routinely in the TΩ range. But achieving this in practise forbids virtually **any** shunt component to a fixed reference voltage such as Ground or VSS, because the leakage through this shunt component will vary stronger than 1 pA per 1 V of input voltage change.

To achieve reliable TΩ input impedances, you can only place shunt components to "guard" rails that move in tandem with the input voltage level.

If you want an AC coupled amplifier, this leads to a chicken-egg problem about the DC voltage point on the amp side of the input capacitor. So one must assign a preferred DC voltage point by other means than by directly tying the input node to Ground with a large resistor.

Comment: Its not AC amplifier but DC. Op90 and Ad620 are DC. If the input impedance is only 10Mohm. does what you mention still valid? Anyway. I removed the negative feedback op90 and connected Aground direct to ground. I only got a flat 4.4volts at the output to the input of the ADC of the HC11. Its as if with zero ground, there is bigger differential at op amps inputs. How come the output of this all ground connection is a flat 4.4V with no waveforms of any kind?

Comment: Even when I set the Vrh of the HC11 to 5 volts so it can encompass the 4.4V output (or input to the ADC) when the negative feedback op-amp was pulled out and connecting Agrnd to real ground. There was still just constant flat waveform output  at 4.4V even when I moved the electrodes. The electrode input measured 0.3 volts, the AD620 output 0.37V with 0.35V reference. Why isn't it showing any waveforms at the output when Aground was not 2V but connected to ground?

Comment: It is clearly an AC amp, it has coupling caps right at the inputs!  This thing is single supply rail which will be why everything is being offset a few volts to allow the doings to swing negative while staying inside the supply rails (And ADC range).

Comment: I played with this AD620 online calculator for hours. Note if you enter 2 volts. It's no longer in the diamond box. https://tools.analog.com/en/diamond/?doc=AN-1401pdf#difL=0.000004&difR=0.000007&difSl=0.000004&gain=50&l=2.2&pr=AD620&r=3&sl=2.2&tab=1&ty=1&vn=0&vp=5&vr=2  I wonder what will happen if I changed the -VS in the actual circuit to -5V. There should be improvement? Also I think you guys are right that the 1000GOhm is internal to the Op-Amp. This s because the AD620 has 10Gohm internal impedance. What Op-Amps have 1000Gohm internal impedance? I guess there is no more 10000GOhm op-amp?